# Optimizing Sqoop data import from MySQL to Hive using import-all-tables

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive, sqoop

I am using Sqoop 1.4.6 to import data from MySQL to Hive using the **import-all-tables** option. The result is ok, but the import process itself is quite slow. For example one of the databases contains 40-50 tables with well under 1 million rows in total, and takes around **25-30 minutes** to complete. Upon investigating, it seems most of the time is spent initialising Hive for each imported table. Testing a plain mysqldump on the same database completes in **under 1 minute**. So the question is how to reduce this initialisation time, if that is the case, for example using a single Hive session?

The import command is:

```
sqoop import-all-tables -Dorg.apache.sqoop.splitter.allow_text_splitter=true --compress --compression-codec=snappy --num-mappers 1 --connect "jdbc:mysql://..." --username ... --password ... --null-string '\\N' --null-non-string '\\N' --hive-drop-import-delims --hive-import --hive-overwrite --hive-database ... --as-textfile --exclude-tables ... --warehouse-dir=...
```

**Update:**

Sqoop version: 1.4.6.2.5.3.0-37

Hive version: 1.2.1000.2.5.3.0-37

Could be related to:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-10319

Answer (score 1):

remove option `--num-mappers 1` to run import with default 4 mappers ***OR*** change it to some higher number `--num-mappers 8` (if hardware allows) - this is to run import with more parellel jobs for tables having primary key, ***AND*** use [`--autoreset-to-one-mapper`](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_purpose_2) option - it will use 1 mapper for table not having primary key. Also use [`--direct`](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_mysql_direct_connector) mode:

```
sqoop import-all-tables \
--connect "jdbc:mysql://..." --username ... \
--password ... \
-Dorg.apache.sqoop.splitter.allow_text_splitter=true \
--compress --compression-codec=snappy \
--num-mappers 8 \
--autoreset-to-one \ 
--direct \
--null-string '\\N' 
...
```

let us know if this improve the performance...

---

***Update:***

> [`--fetch-size=<n>`](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/70258/sqoop-performance-tuning.html) - Where  represents the number of entries that
>   Sqoop must fetch at a time. Default is 1000.
>
> Increase the value of the fetch-size argument based on the volume of
>   data that need to read. Set the value based on the available memory
>   and bandwidth.

---

> increasing mapper memory from current value to some higher number:
>   example: `sqoop import-all-tables -D mapreduce.map.memory.mb=2048 -D mapreduce.map.java.opts=-Xmx1024m <sqoop options>`

---

***[Sqoop Performance Tuning Best Practices](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/70258/sqoop-performance-tuning.html)***

Tune the following Sqoop arguments in JDBC connection or Sqoop mapping to optimize performance

- batch (for export)
- split-by and boundary-query (not needed since we
  are suing `--autoreset-to-one-mapper`, can't be use with `import-all-tables`)
- direct
- fetch-size
- num-mapper

Comment: It looks like I can't use `--direct` with `--hive-drop-import-delims`, but will try your other suggestions and get back...

Comment: Pretty much the same result; around 25 minutes per database. I tried also with databases varying in the number of total rows, but with roughly the same amount of tables, and the total times taken are quite close to each other. Seems like there is some constant time per table, which isn't relative to the amount of data in them.

Comment: can you try with increasing mapper memory from current value to some higher number?: `sqoop import-all-tables -D mapreduce.map.memory.mb=2048 -D mapreduce.map.java.opts=-Xmx1024m <sqoop options>`

Comment: @RonakPatel you covered many good points. But OP is interested in reducing **hive initialization time**. Because for every hive import on database means hive import on each table (_excluding `--exclude-tables`_) a new hive session created to fire `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS..` and `LOAD DATA INPATH....` command. OP wants to reduce this time. Do you have any suggestion for it?

Comment: Thank you for the many suggestions, but as noted above, probably most of the time is spent somewhere else. Tuning sqoop parameters gave little to none improvement, even for a database practically empty of data. From the output, I can see LOAD DATA times in the ballpark of 0.1-0.2 seconds, so for a total time I was expecting something closer to that of a plain mysqldump.

Comment: @TuomasTikka LOAD DATA is not taking much time, sqoop command is faster now, What is it that causing delay here?